# xargs, sh -c, and variables

Tags: shell, variables, sh, xargs

How can I pass my variables inside an `sh -c` command?

```
~$ echo $from
/tmp/from
~$ echo $to
/tmp/to
~$ find /tmp/from -type f | xargs -r -d '\n' -n1 sh -c 'f="$0" ; a=`echo "$f" | sed "s|^$from/|$to/|"` ; echo "${f}\t${a}"'
/tmp/from/lulu  /tmp/from/lulu
/tmp/from/toto  /tmp/from/toto
```

It looks like my `$from` and `$to` are not getting inside ... I tried double quotes and escaping inside quotes, but without much success so far.

Thanks!

P.S.: input files list is normally stored in a file, `find` is only here for the sake of example.

Comment: `sh -c 'script using $0 and $1' "$from" $to"`?

Comment: How to articulate with the input pipe from `xargs`?

Comment: It is unclear what are you trying to do. If you are trying to process the output of `find` line by line, then you shouldn't use `xargs` as it combines the entire output into a single string of "arguments". Instead you can use a loop like `find ... | while read file; do do_something_with "$file"; done`

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov To be safe, don't treat `$0` as a positional parameter; it's one of the special parameters. Just provide a dummy value for `$0` if you don't care about it.  `sh -c 'script using $1 and $2' _ "$from" "$to"`.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, thanks for your answer, but I specifically mentioned that list of files is normally contained in a file, I used `find` here only for the purpose of the example.